# Failing to load pillar library in R

Tags: r

I am receiving an unclear error message when I try to install the pillar package. As I just found out, it also happens for the load of other packages as well: 'broom', 'dtplyr', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'ggplot2', 'modelr', 'pillar' (all dependencies for tidyverse).

I don't recall ever installing it before but for some reason pillar and many packages that use it as a requirement are gone.

Below is the error message:

```
> install.packages("pillar")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
pillar  1.4.3  1.6.4             FALSE

installing the source package ‘pillar’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.6.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1097062 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'pillar' ...
** package 'pillar' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'pillar'
    finding HTML links ... done
    align                                   html  
    char                                    html  
    colonnade                               html  
    ctl_new_pillar                          html  
    deprecated                              html  
    dim_desc                                html  
    expect_known_display                    html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeEGAZW/R.INSTALLce8619d777b/pillar/man/expect_known_display.Rd:31: missing file link 'expect_snapshot'
    extra_cols                              html  
    format_glimpse                          html  
    format_tbl                              html  
    format_type_sum                         html  
    get_extent                              html  
    glimpse                                 html  
    new_ornament                            html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ...
Error: unknown input format
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/pillar'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried:

- using R instead of RStudio
- Installing from Source or precompiled
- searching for the pillar folder in the library folders and deleting it (it doesn't exist)

What are my options? Could this be resolved by uninstalling R and Reinstalling it? Can I manually (?) install this package?

As per jared_mamrod's suggestion, below is the full output when I try to install tidyverse:

```
* installing *source* package 'blob' ...
** package 'blob' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'blob'
    finding HTML links ... done
    as.blob                                 html  
    blob                                    html  
    vec_cast.blob                           html  
    vec_ptype2.blob                         html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpmk8NP2/R.INSTALL39c04f94370/blob/man/vec_ptype2.blob.Rd:18: file link 'stop_incompatible_type' in package 'vctrs' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpmk8NP2/R.INSTALL39c04f94370/blob/man/vec_ptype2.blob.Rd:22: file link 'stop_incompatible_type' in package 'vctrs' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (blob)
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'tzdb' ...
** package 'tzdb' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cpp11/include"     -I../inst/include -DINSTALL=dummy -DAUTO_DOWNLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=0 -DONLY_C_LOCALE=1   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c api.cpp -o api.o
In file included from api.cpp:3:0:
C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cpp11/include/cpp11/protect.hpp:430:1: warning: 'cpp11::preserved' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 preserved;
 ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cpp11/include"     -I../inst/include -DINSTALL=dummy -DAUTO_DOWNLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=0 -DONLY_C_LOCALE=1   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c cpp11.cpp -o cpp11.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cpp11/include"     -I../inst/include -DINSTALL=dummy -DAUTO_DOWNLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=0 -DONLY_C_LOCALE=1   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c names.cpp -o names.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cpp11/include"     -I../inst/include -DINSTALL=dummy -DAUTO_DOWNLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=0 -DONLY_C_LOCALE=1   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c path.cpp -o path.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cpp11/include"     -I../inst/include -DINSTALL=dummy -DAUTO_DOWNLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=0 -DONLY_C_LOCALE=1   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c tz.cpp -o tz.o
tz.cpp:236:1: warning: 'std::string get_known_folder(const GUID&)' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 get_known_folder(const GUID& folderid)
 ^
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cpp11/include"     -I../inst/include -DINSTALL=dummy -DAUTO_DOWNLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=0 -DONLY_C_LOCALE=1   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c version.cpp -o version.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o tzdb.dll tmp.def api.o cpp11.o names.o path.o tz.o version.o -lpthread -lole32 -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tzdb/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'tzdb'
    finding HTML links ... done
    tzdb-package                            html  
    tzdb_initialize                         html  
    tzdb_names                              html  
    tzdb_path                               html  
    tzdb_version                            html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (tzdb)
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'callr' ...
** package 'callr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'processx' 3.4.2 is being loaded, but >= 3.5.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/callr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/callr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'knitr' ...
** package 'knitr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.13 is being loaded, but >= 0.21 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/knitr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/knitr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'withr' ...
** package 'withr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'withr'
    finding HTML links ... done
    defer                                   html  
    devices                                 html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp67GeMt/R.INSTALL3b2432723bf0/withr/man/devices.Rd:228: file link 'X11' in package 'grDevices' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    makevars_user                           html  
    set_makevars                            html  
    with_                                   html  
    with_collate                            html  
    with_connection                         html  
    with_db_connection                      html  
    with_dir                                html  
    with_envvar                             html  
    with_file                               html  
    with_gctorture2                         html  
    with_language                           html  
    with_libpaths                           html  
    with_locale                             html  
    with_makevars                           html  
    with_options                            html  
    with_package                            html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp67GeMt/R.INSTALL3b2432723bf0/withr/man/with_package.Rd:68: file link '.libPaths' in package 'base' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    with_par                                html  
    with_path                               html  
    with_rng_version                        html  
    with_seed                               html  
    with_sink                               html  
    with_temp_libpaths                      html  
    with_tempfile                           html  
    with_timezone                           html  
    withr                                   html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (withr)
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'crayon' ...
** package 'crayon' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'crayon'
    finding HTML links ... done
    chr                                     html  
    col_align                               html  
    col_nchar                               html  
    col_strsplit                            html  
    col_substr                              html  
    col_substring                           html  
    combine_styles                          html  
    concat                                  html  
    crayon                                  html  
    drop_style                              html  
    has_color                               html  
    has_style                               html  
    hyperlink                               html  
    make_style                              html  
    num_ansi_colors                         html  
    num_colors                              html  
    show_ansi_colors                        html  
    start.crayon                            html  
    strip_style                             html  
    style                                   html  
    styles                                  html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (crayon)
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'forcats' ...
** package 'forcats' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'forcats'
    finding HTML links ... done
    as_factor                               html  
    fct_anon                                html  
    fct_c                                   html  
    fct_collapse                            html  
    fct_count                               html  
   [...]
    lvls                                    html  
    lvls_union                              html  
    pipe                                    html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmqkOIF/R.INSTALL61462d171a0/forcats/man/pipe.Rd:10: file link '%>%' in package 'magrittr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (forcats)
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'hms' ...
** package 'hms' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'hms'
    finding HTML links ... done
    Deprecated                              html  
    hms-package                             html  
    hms                                     html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ...
Error: unknown input format
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/hms'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/hms'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'httr' ...
** package 'httr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'httr'
    finding HTML links ... done
    BROWSE                                  html  
    DELETE                                  html  
    GET                                     html  
    HEAD                                    html  
    PATCH                                   html  
    POST                                    html  
    PUT                                     html  
    RETRY                                   html  
    Token-class                             html  
    VERB                                    html  
    add_headers                             html  
    authenticate                            html  
    cache_info                              html  
    config                                  html  
    content                                 html  
Error: unknown input format
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/httr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/httr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'rstudioapi' ...
** package 'rstudioapi' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'rstudioapi'
    finding HTML links ... done
    addTheme                                html  
    applyTheme                              html  
    askForPassword                          html  
    askForSecret                            html  
    bugReport                               html  
    build-tools                             html  
    callFun                                 html  
    chunk-callbacks                         html  
    convertTheme                            html  
    createProjectTemplate                   html  
    dictionaries                            html  
    document_position                       html  
    document_range                          html  
    executeCommand                          html  
    file-dialogs                            html  
    filesPaneNavigate                       html  
    [...] 
    writeRStudioPreference                  html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rstudioapi)
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'gargle' ...
** package 'gargle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'gargle'
    finding HTML links ... done
    AuthState-class                         html  
    Gargle-class                            html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAfsqMI/R.INSTALL34387bd29/gargle/man/Gargle-class.Rd:29: file link 'Token' in package 'httr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAfsqMI/R.INSTALL34387bd29/gargle/man/Gargle-class.Rd:29: file link 'Token2.0' in package 'httr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    GceToken                                html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAfsqMI/R.INSTALL34387bd29/gargle/man/GceToken.Rd:17: file link 'Token' in package 'httr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAfsqMI/R.INSTALL34387bd29/gargle/man/GceToken.Rd:17: file link 'Token2.0' in package 'httr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    WifToken                                html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAfsqMI/R.INSTALL34387bd29/gargle/man/WifToken.Rd:16: file link 'Token' in package 'httr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAfsqMI/R.INSTALL34387bd29/gargle/man/WifToken.Rd:16: file link 'Token2.0' in package 'httr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    bulletize                               html  
    cred_funs                               html  
    credentials_app_default                 html  
    credentials_byo_oauth2                  html  
    [...]
    request_develop                         html  
    request_make                            html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ...
Error: unknown input format
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/gargle'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/gargle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gargle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'dbplyr' ...
** package 'dbplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'dplyr' 0.8.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.4 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dbplyr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dbplyr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'dtplyr' ...
** package 'dtplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'data.table' 1.12.8 is being loaded, but >= 1.13.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dtplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dtplyr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dtplyr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'pillar'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'pillar' ...
** package 'pillar' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'pillar'
    finding HTML links ... done
    align                                   html  
    char                                    html  
    colonnade                               html  
    ctl_new_pillar                          html  
    deprecated                              html  
    dim_desc                                html  
    expect_known_display                    html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4AK743/R.INSTALL95c2c8b4bf/pillar/man/expect_known_display.Rd:31: missing file link 'expect_snapshot'
    extra_cols                              html  
    format_glimpse                          html  
    format_tbl                              html  
    format_type_sum                         html  
    get_extent                              html  
    glimpse                                 html  
    new_ornament                            html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ...
Error: unknown input format
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/pillar'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'reprex' ...
** package 'reprex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'reprex'
    finding HTML links ... done
    reprex-package                          html  
    reprex                                  html  
    reprex_addin                            html  
    reprex_document                         html  
    reprex_locale                           html  
    reprex_options                          html  
    reprex_render                           html  
    reprex_venue                            html  
    un-reprex                               html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (reprex)
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'rvest' ...
** package 'rvest' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'rvest'
    finding HTML links ... done
    google_form                             html  
    html_attr                               html  
    html_children                           html  
    html_element                            html  
    html_encoding_guess                     html  
    html_form                               html  
    html_name                               html  
    html_table                              html  
    html_text                               html  
    minimal_html                            html  
    reexports                               html  
    rename                                  html  
    repair_encoding                         html  
    rvest-package                           html  
    session                                 html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rvest)
In R CMD INSTALL
ERROR: dependency 'ggplot2' is not available for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/broom'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'pillar' is not available for package 'googledrive'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/googledrive'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googledrive’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'googledrive' is not available for package 'googlesheets4'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/googlesheets4'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'broom' is not available for package 'modelr'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/modelr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'broom', 'dtplyr', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'ggplot2', 'modelr', 'pillar' are not available for package 'tidyverse'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyverse'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoTgubv\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: If you install the tidyverse without & with dependencies, does that solve your problem? (i.e. `install.packages("tidyverse")` and/or `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE )`)

Comment: Interestingly the same error also occurs for many other packages that I could have sworn were already loaded but are not. It is almost all of the dependencies for tidyverse: 'broom', 'dtplyr', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'ggplot2', 'modelr', 'pillar'

Comment: Perhaps try `remove.packages("tidyverse"); install.packages("tidyverse")` and edit your question to include the output/errors

Comment: R tells me that there is no package called tidyverse. So this is not installed. I am pasting my error message when installing tidyverse in my submission above.

Comment: Based on the warnings / error messages you are running into compatibility issues due to the old version of R you are using. You could try installing an older version of the tidyverse (i.e. `require(devtools); install_version("tidyverse", version = "1.2.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`) or, the more practical option, update R to the newest version.

Comment: Thank you. I will try updating. Let's hope this works. Thanks for your ideas so far.